# OpenSuse 11.4 hard free space decreases to zero without any running programs

Tags: hard-drive, vnc, opensuse

I have linux OpenSuse 11.4 on my HP proliant server and I always connect to it with TightVCN. The server settings are:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 508283
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 55311708
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 508283
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 92324960
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I had not this problem before but, recently, with or without any uses, the hard free space rapidly decrease until it reaches to zero (during less than 24 hours). When this declination starts the VNC connection losses without any warnings. It forced me to restart server manually. The first restarting restore VNC connection and the second restart could restore the lost free space. This cycle never stops. Therefore, I would like to know how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you trace what is using that space?

I had similar problem some time ago with log files that samba was creating. I run out of space on my 6TB server :)

Another thing it might be is mysql log file. Sometimes when you leave mysql logging it will log a lot of stuff and if it gets mental it will create massive logs and you will runout of space.

Just a thought. ;)

Comment: Even without any uses I encountered this. How you fixed it?

Comment: In samba config change this:


`[global]
# Debug logging information
 log level = 2
 log file = /var/log/samba.log.%m
 max log size = 50
 debug timestamp = yes`